# How do I change the word as "out of stock" in sidebar filter magento 2?

Tags: magento2

[image]

See **attached image**, out of stock word change in filter sidebar magento 2? I want to change the word as "Out of stock" to "Back to back" **Please send me the theme file path so its help me.**

Comment: Change means what you want to this statement "out of stock"?

Comment: I wan to change from "Out Of stock" to Back to Back